# How to remove Google Web Elements from google new Iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, google-news

How to remove Google Web Elements from google news of iframe.

```
<iframe frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 border=0 style="border:0;margin:0;width:275px;height:300px;" src="http://www.google.com/uds/modules/elements/newsshow/iframe.html?rsz=large&format=275x300&hl=en&q=google&element=true" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a div as wrapper, with `position: relative;` then, set a `position: absolute;` to your `iframe`, and set negative position to left.

http://jsfiddle.net/3YX9f/

HTML:

```
<div class="frame-wrap">
    <iframe frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 border=0 style="border:0;margin:0;width:800px;height:300px;" src="http://www.google.com/uds/modules/elements/newsshow/iframe.html?rsz=large&format=275x300&hl=en&q=google&element=true" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="gnews"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.frame-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.gnews {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: -172px;
}
```

Comment: well thanx for the answer but If I want to change width of iframe's content how it possible